# i want to make Node Mcu a bride for other devices but its self connected with home wifi not providing internet to others

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

i there!
i have Node Mcu which i want to connected with my home wifi 
after it it made it own station mode then i want to make it access point for other 
but now problem is that it is now in both mode mean (AP+Station ).
when i want to connect any other phone or Pc  it connected successfully 
but not providing internet to other devices.
Question?

1. is problem in wifi configuration of acess point?
2. which ip,gate way and subnet mask i would assign to the access point?

Comment: I don't understand, how you have configured the Node MCU. Please provide a minimal working sketch, that shows your problem. Gateway and subnet mask have to match the corresponding values of your network, that you connect to. If the gateway isn't correctly set, you won't have internet connection, since the routing won't work

Comment: the NodeMcu is not a router. there are attempts to make a router application for esp8266, but not with Arduino

Answer (score 1):

The NodeMCU under the Arduino framework cannot do what you want.  There are basically three methods for what you want:

1. Configure the IP stack to enable routing - not possible in Arduino, and also requires configuration of your upstream router to work.
2. Configure the IP stack to enable routing and Network Address Translation - not possible in Arduino, and I am not sure if the stack even supports NAT.
3. Write a sketch to act as a proxy server - only works for certain types of traffic (HTTP) and requires a lot of coding. May be possible, but not an easy task.

1) and 2) certainly can't be don in Arduino. There are rumours on the internet that it is possible to configure and compile your own lwIP stack version with routing enabled, but that is so far outside the scope of this website.

Option 3 is the more realistic, but certainly not something even I would consider doing. Creating a sketch that works like [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/), for example, would be a mammoth task, and may even hit the limitations of the ESP8266.

It would be more beneficial to perhaps get an old wireless router that is supported by OpenWRT and learn how to hack that to act as you want.